# Tsqlt with XML Schema collection

Tags: tsqlt

I am currently working on a table schema that has a column that refers to an XML schema collection. After faking the table in my unit test and running the test I got an error message: 'Collection specified does not exist in metadata'.

I have tried to create xml schema collection before faking. but this still causes an error.

Anyone have idea.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please can you supply the table schema and the test that gave you the error. You have not explained what you are trying to test.